# Data always goes to partition 0 when using kafka-go and round-robin balancer

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm using the kafka-go library to write messages to Kafka. I'm using a round-robin balancer, but the data always goes to partition 0. I have tried omitting the Partition field for all messages, but the data still goes to partition 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
func main() {
    var logger = logger.Logger()

    w := kafka.Writer{
        Addr:     kafka.TCP("localhost:9092", "localhost:9093", "localhost:9094"),
        Balancer: &kafka.RoundRobin{},
    }
    messages := []kafka.Message{
        {
            Topic: "first-topic",
            Key:   []byte("test"),
            Value: []byte("value"),
        },
        {
            Topic: "second-topic",
            Key:   []byte("test2"),
            Value: []byte("value2"),
        },
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(messages); i++ {
        w.WriteMessages(context.Background(), messages[i])
    }

    if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
        logger.Fatal().Msg("failed to close writer:")
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be specific and name the library used properly.

Comment: im using https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

Answer (score 1):

Round Robin partitioning only occurs when the key of a message is not defined. Otherwise, the partition is computed from the hash of that key (test and test2 may hash similarly to arrive in the same partition)